# Weird behaviour when the inventory loads c# unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making the RPG with save and load inventory function. I am using `PlayerPerfs`, but I have a problem. Let's say the `ID` of items when I save like this: **18, 19, 20 and 21**, but when I load, it become like this: **20, 21, 22 and 23**, seems like the items did not in the correct order, and every time it loads, it will increase the `ID` by 2 from the last saved. Here is image of it when I save and load:

**Save:**

[image]

**Load:**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public static void SaveItem()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Inventory: " + i, inventory[i].itemID);
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to save items to the database!");
    }
}

public static void LoadItem()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            inventory[i] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Inventory: " + i, -1) >= 0 ? ItemDatabase.items[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Inventory: " + i)] : new ItemManager();
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to load items from the database!");
    }
}
```

Here is the code of item database:

```
private void Start()
{
    items.Add(new ItemManager(0, "Small Health Potion", "Recovers 10% of Health Points", 0, (int)_smallHealth, 0, 0, 50, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(1, "Medium Health Potion", "Recovers 20% of Health Points", 0, (int)_mediumHealth, 0, 0, 100, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(2, "Large Health Potion", "Recovers 40% of Health Points", 0, (int)_largeHealth, 0, 0, 200, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(3, "Small Mana Potion", "Recovers 5% of Mana Points", 0, 0, (int)_smallMana, 0, 50, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(4, "Medium Mana Potion", "Recovers 10% of Mana Points", 0, 0, (int)_mediumMana, 0, 100, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(5, "Large Mana Potion", "Recovers 20% of Mana Points", 0, 0, (int)_largeMana, 0, 200, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

    items.Add(new ItemManager(8, "Banana", "Recovers 25% of Health Points and 5% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_bananaHealth, (int)_bananaMana, 0, 225, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(9, "Grape", "Recovers 45% of Health Points and 15% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_grapeHealth, (int)_grapeMana, 0, 350, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(10, "Orange", "Recovers 65% Health Points and 25% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_orangeHealth, (int)_orangeMana, 0, 475, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(11, "Pineapple", "Recovers 100% Health Points and 40% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_pineappleHealth, (int)_pineappleMana, 0, 600, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

    items.Add(new ItemManager(12, "Blue Katana", "A blue katana that made by Japanese people", 75, 0, 0, 0, 150, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(13, "Yellow Katana", "A yellow katana that made by Japanese people", 150, 0, 0, 0, 300, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(14, "Fire Katana", "A fire katana that made by Japanese people", 200, 0, 0, 0, 400, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(15, "Dark Katana", "A dark katana that made by Japanese people", 450, 0, 0, 0, 900, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(16, "Ice Katana", "An ice katana that made by Japanese people", 600, 0, 0, 0, 1200, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(17, "Silver Katana", "An ultimate silver katana that made by Japanese people", 1000, 0, 0, 0, 2000, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

    items.Add(new ItemManager(18, "Ultimate Head Armor", "An ultimate head armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Head));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(19, "Ultimate Body Armor", "An ultimate body armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Body));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(20, "Ultimate Hand Armor", "An ultimate hand armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Hand));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(21, "Ultimate Leg Armor", "An ultimate leg armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Leg));

    items.Add(new ItemManager(22, "Wind Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(23, "Earth Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(24, "Fire Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(25, "Ice Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

    items.Add(new ItemManager(26, "Wind Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(27, "Earth Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(28, "Fire Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
    items.Add(new ItemManager(29, "Ice Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
}
```

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your items list consists of elements from 0-29 but your list is made upto 27 elements only where you have **skipped two numbers 6 and 7** in elements database. The following is the correction to the database has been made:

```
items.Add(new ItemManager(0, "Small Health Potion", "Recovers 10% of Health Points", 0, (int)_smallHealth, 0, 0, 50, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(1, "Medium Health Potion", "Recovers 20% of Health Points", 0, (int)_mediumHealth, 0, 0, 100, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(2, "Large Health Potion", "Recovers 40% of Health Points", 0, (int)_largeHealth, 0, 0, 200, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(3, "Small Mana Potion", "Recovers 5% of Mana Points", 0, 0, (int)_smallMana, 0, 50, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(4, "Medium Mana Potion", "Recovers 10% of Mana Points", 0, 0, (int)_mediumMana, 0, 100, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(5, "Large Mana Potion", "Recovers 20% of Mana Points", 0, 0, (int)_largeMana, 0, 200, ItemManager.ItemType.Consumable, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

items.Add(new ItemManager(6, "Banana", "Recovers 25% of Health Points and 5% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_bananaHealth, (int)_bananaMana, 0, 225, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(7, "Grape", "Recovers 45% of Health Points and 15% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_grapeHealth, (int)_grapeMana, 0, 350, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(8, "Orange", "Recovers 65% Health Points and 25% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_orangeHealth, (int)_orangeMana, 0, 475, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(9, "Pineapple", "Recovers 100% Health Points and 40% of Mana Points", 0, (int)_pineappleHealth, (int)_pineappleMana, 0, 600, ItemManager.ItemType.Foods, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

items.Add(new ItemManager(10, "Blue Katana", "A blue katana that made by Japanese people", 75, 0, 0, 0, 150, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(11, "Yellow Katana", "A yellow katana that made by Japanese people", 150, 0, 0, 0, 300, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(12, "Fire Katana", "A fire katana that made by Japanese people", 200, 0, 0, 0, 400, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(13, "Dark Katana", "A dark katana that made by Japanese people", 450, 0, 0, 0, 900, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(14, "Ice Katana", "An ice katana that made by Japanese people", 600, 0, 0, 0, 1200, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(15, "Silver Katana", "An ultimate silver katana that made by Japanese people", 1000, 0, 0, 0, 2000, ItemManager.ItemType.Weapon, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

items.Add(new ItemManager(16, "Ultimate Head Armor", "An ultimate head armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Head));
items.Add(new ItemManager(17, "Ultimate Body Armor", "An ultimate body armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Body));
items.Add(new ItemManager(18, "Ultimate Hand Armor", "An ultimate hand armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Hand));
items.Add(new ItemManager(19, "Ultimate Leg Armor", "An ultimate leg armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Leg));

items.Add(new ItemManager(20, "Wind Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(21, "Earth Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(22, "Fire Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(23, "Ice Ring", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Ring, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));

items.Add(new ItemManager(24, "Wind Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(25, "Earth Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(26, "Fire Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
items.Add(new ItemManager(27, "Ice Necklace", "Just an accessory with no effect to your status", 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, ItemManager.ItemType.Necklace, default(ItemManager.ArmorType)));
```

you are saving in player prefs using item id. consider 16 as item id you are saving so when you are trying to retrieve item using players prefs it will give you 16 but when you apply it to your list the 16 item will point to item in the old database. Also it will give error when you are trying to acess at 28 and 29 position as there are no elements existing at that position. Although your code will work for items from 0-5 but as the elements are missing in the order it will not work after 5

```
"18, "Ultimate Head Armor", "An ultimate head armor that protect the user", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, ItemManager.ItemType.Armor, ItemManager.ArmorType.Head));"
```

Comment: lol, did not notice that and this question seems like makes me damn stupid to not notice that. thank you anyway